# Refreshing an entire html/php page smoothly

Tags: php, html, iframe

Case: A php page with SQL needs to be refreshed every 30 seconds, but due to hardware limitations, there is a 0.5-2 second blank screen. Values do need to be retrieved from the database on every refresh, but the idea is to use a kind of seamless transitional effect, but where the transition is from one page to itself. 15 years ago or so, I experimented with what is described here: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/meta-tag-hidden-features/ and I need something similar, though I am not even entirely sure that it would work. The page is very light and does not contain any images, so the load time is not the issue.
So, in short: How do I make it "impossible" to see that the page is refreshed, though values might have changed (or at least without the page going momentarily blank)?

I have tried numerous approaches with js and ajax functions to take care of the reloading instead of `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`, but none of them seem to be able to do what I want.

Comment: Can't you load those values in asynchronously (via AJAX) and add them to the page via JavaScript?

Comment: The only way it seems possible is using AJAX as mentioned in above comment by @Ivar.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ivar and $usman-afzal, the issue was resolved using Ajax. Having no experience with Ajax/jQuery whatsoever, it took a while to get all the different values right and put them in their correct positions, but I succeeded, so thanks for the tip.